# file_column to carrierwave conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm rebuilding a site that was created in 2005 on rails 2.0.1.  It uses file_column for image management.  I'd like to use carrierwave with AWS3.  Has anyone performed this conversion?

There are more than 50k images to transfer and load.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a solution similar to this. I have a project using Rails 1.1.6 using file_column.

The part that I don't understand is the logic behind file_column's storage. It seems completely random in how it stores files in directories.

I'm writing a script that moves all files into the root folder, clearing all frivolous sub-directories out. Then it will take the file name and perform a look up to find out which record the asset belongs to. Then I will re-upload each file.